# wordpress to pass subpage as parameter

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I would like to pass URL with subpages to the main page with subpages as a parameter.

For example, URL `/contact/info` would show a page `/contact` with `info` as a parameter.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to show only parent page's content while subpage remail as url param?

Comment: Yes, I want to create only one page /contact with a parameter info, but parameter can be changed.

Comment: But we need to be aware of the parameter value? is it a child page of contact?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use the parameter value. It's not a child page.

Answer (score 1):

1 : Add Custom URL Rewrite Rules..

```
function slug_url_rewrite_rule(){

    $page_id = 7151; //page_id to show content

    $url_parameter = 'subpage'; //parameter name

    $page_slug = 'contact'; // page slug to match page

    add_rewrite_rule( '^'.$page_slug.'/([-a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id='.$page_id.'&'.$url_parameter.'=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}

add_action( 'init', 'slug_url_rewrite_rule' ); // rewrite url rule
```

2 : Add custom query_var...

```
function slug_add_custom_query_vars( $query_vars ){

    $query_vars[] = 'subpage'; // parameter name

    return $query_vars;

}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'slug_add_custom_query_vars' ); // add custom query_var
```

3 : Flush URL Rewrite...

> Go to **Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes**

4 : Get Parameter value..

```
global $wp_query;

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['subpage'])){
    print $wp_query->query_vars['subpage'];

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sajjad Hossain Sagor, Not sure where those code should be and how can user pass the subpage parameter?

Comment: Worked first time. Thanks Sajjad :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a page call Contact and then create another page called Info and in the attributes box, select Contact as the parent of the Info page.

Comment: no, I don't want another info page. I want a contact page with "info" parameter passed into.

Comment: Considering the info is a slug, they passing it into the URL normally, for example, `contact/?subPg=info` and in your PHP file you can use `get_page_by_path('contact/'.$_GET['subPg']);`. It should get you the desired page object,

Comment: how can I change contact/info to contact/?subPg=info ?